# Haml rendering error on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, haml, passenger

I'm writing a Rails 3 application on Mac OSX and it runs fine under both development and production.  When I deploy the app with Passenger I get a error in one of my views.  This is how the view looks like:

```
%p#refresh= link_to 'Refresh', '#', id: "refreshAreaLink"

#newAreaParagraph
  = link_to 'New area', '#', id: "createNewAreaLink"

- for area_group in AreaGroup.all
  .areaGroup
    = area_group.name
  %ul
  - for area in Area.find_all_by_area_group_id(area_group.id)
    %li.areaList
      = link_to area.name, area, :remote => true, :class => "areaLink", :id => "prufa"
.areaGroup
  No group
- for area in Area.find_all_by_area_group_id(nil)
  %li.areaList
    = link_to area.name, area, :remote => true, :class => "areaLink", :id => "prufa"
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
Started GET "/" for 192.168.102.28 at Sat Sep 10 15:36:20 +0000 2011
  Processing by MapController#index as HTML
Rendered areas/_sidebar.html.haml (4.9ms)
Rendered map/index.html.haml within layouts/map (7.8ms)
Completed   in 224ms

ActionView::Template::Error (compile error
/var/shellopt/app/views/areas/_sidebar.html.haml:1: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')'
...e((link_to 'Refresh', '#', id: "refreshAreaLink"
                              ^
/var/shellopt/app/views/areas/_sidebar.html.haml:4: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')'
...( link_to 'New area', '#', id: "createNewAreaLink"
                              ^):
    1: %p#refresh= link_to 'Refresh', '#', id: "refreshAreaLink"
    2: 
    3: #newAreaParagraph
    4:   = link_to 'New area', '#', id: "createNewAreaLink"
  app/views/areas/_sidebar.html.haml:22:in `compile'
  app/views/layouts/map.html.haml:24:in `_app_views_layouts_map_html_haml___245337611_70182228267100_0'
```

Is there something obvious I'm doing wrong?

Regards,
Johann

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like line #4 is using the new Ruby 1.9 hash syntax of `key: value` instead of `:key => value`. Is your production environment running Ruby 1.8? If so, you'll either need to upgrade to 1.9, or use the Ruby 1.8 compatible format:

```
  = link_to 'New area', '#', :id => "createNewAreaLink"
```

Comment: Correct - I was using 1.8.x on production and when I fixed the link based on your suggestion the error disapeared.  Next step for me is to update ruby on production to be the same version.  Thank you very much Dylan.